# matlab takes too much ram, what's wrong?

Tags: windows, memory, matlab

[image: Screenshot of TaskManager]

On my win10, I have **MATLAB 2016a**. when I use task manager to watch the system, I found that MATLAB takes too much memory. On the other hand, mathematica use very little memory, both of them are not running programs.

Can someone tell me is this normal? I don't expect MATLAB to take so much memory without running any code.

Comment: Is this when MATLAB is running, but you didn't process any code? My MATLAB also takes about 500MB of RAM without running anything, just opening the program. I tested this on 2 separate computers, both with MATLAB 2016a

Comment: @BramMooij yes, free loading

Comment: See the edit to my last comment for some more information. So far, it seems like normal behaviour to me, but I have no explanation for it.

Comment: OK, maybe matlab is very memory consuming...

Comment: I noticed that after time the memory usage drops to about 200 MB. Still have no more of a clue as to what causes this, but maybe you can verify whether you see the same behaviour. Perhaps it already reserves some memory, because it expects you to use it. This prevents another program from coming along, reserving this RAM, making MATLAB unusable. If it then figures out that you wont be using it much, it can drop the "reservation".

Comment: @BramMooij Mine has no such behavior. Maybe this is due to windows system optimization, not malab it self. I guess your other programs take much ram, windows find matlab is not working, then it cut matlab's memory usage...

Comment: I am never near using all my RAM, so it can't be due to that. However, it can still be a Windows optimisation where it reserves the RAM only when it thinkas it will be used within some minutes. Do you see the RAM usage of MATLAB go down when you use all of the remaining RAM for something else? Perhaps RAM management is more aggressive on Windows 7 (I use Windows 7) because computers are becoming more powerful.